# Вопрос о пунктуации: нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Без языка не было бы самого человека, потому что все то, что есть в нем человеческого(,) связано с языком, выражается в языке и закрепляется в языке.

Answer (score 1):

Придаточное предложение здесь должно выделяться запятыми с двух сторон. Нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором одно придаточное предложение находится **внутри** другого.

*Без языка не было бы самого человека,* [почему?] *потому что все **то,*** [что?] ***что есть в нем человеческого,*** связано с языком, выражается в языке и закрепляется в языке.

Между указательным местоимением **то** и союзным словом **что** ставится запятая, в конце придаточного предложения также ставится запятая — если придаточное предложение стоит в середине главного, то оно отделяется от главного с двух сторон.

[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)